# create visualization by word count frequency in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, nlp, visualization

I have a visualization task wherein I'm meant to make a visualization on the basis of word count frequency and I want to get some experience using D3.js.

Are there any GitHub projects that demonstrate this functionality or tutorials on this subject?

On Google there are many things about Word Clouds that are crowding up the search results for these key words, but I don't want to make a word cloud per se, more of a visual representation of frequency.

Comment: So what kind of chart do you want to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jason Davies: https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/#%2F%2Fwww.jasondavies.com%2Fwordcloud%2Fabout%2F

and the Github: https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud